# redux-api-middleware persiting state from two different API calls

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-api-middleware

Does anyone know/used redux-api-middleware ? I've got problem with persisting state from two different API calls.
I mean I can’t execute “this.props.fetchMessage(‘Hi!’)” and “this.props.fetchUser()” alongside because if the last one is executed then the first is overwritten by the latter. 
Does anyone know why It doesn’t keep the state from two calls ?

Link to github -> https://github.com/paveu/redux_jwt_auth/blob/master/frontend/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

I messed up with creating User reducer that's why I failed invoking two APIs in the same time. I've done what I wanted to achieve.